# Using a WooCommerce hook on category page causes price display to mess up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to display some fields on the category product list page and the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook. My information comes out perfectly, except it causes EACH product to display ALL the prices of the products on that page. If I remove my hook it works right again.
I added this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'paradigm_custom_category_display', 5 );
function paradigm_custom_category_display() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_short_description()) {
        ?>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title pp-shortdescription">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) ?>
        </h2>   
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <div class="pp-block">
    <?php
    if(get_field('author_name')) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-author"><span>Author: </span><a href="<?php the_field('author_link'); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_field('author_name'); ?></a></div>
        <?php   
    }
    if(get_field('pages')) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-pages"><span>Pages: </span><?php the_field('pages'); ?></div>
        <?php   
    }   
    if(get_field('size')) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-size"><span>Size: </span><?php the_field('size'); ?></div>
        <?php   
    }   
    if(get_field('isbn')) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-isbn"><span>ISBN: </span><?php the_field('isbn'); ?></div>
        <?php   
    }   
    if(get_field('binding')) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-binding"><span>Binding: </span><?php the_field('binding'); ?></div>
        <?php   
    }
    ?>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

And that works for my new category information display. BUT EACH product shown also shows the price of ALL the products on the page now:

[image]

I removed each block of my function and that made no difference. The only way the price goes back to the correct display is not putting in the hook at all. I am new to this and lost. Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: There is still an answer below waiting for your feedback please.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are displaying a link inside an existing linked content (not allowing links).

You will need to change this line removing the author link:

```html
<div class="pp-author"><span>Author: </span><a href="<?php the_field('author_link'); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_field('author_name'); ?></a></div>
```

like:

```html
<div class="pp-author"><span>Author: </span><?php the_field('author_name'); ?></div>
```

**Also be sure that in the product short description displayed content, there are no links.**

This should solve this double link issue *(but maybe not this pricing strange glitch)*

---

Now you should try to buffer the outputted content, as it can solve some strange issues. I have also restricted the allowed HTML tags in the product short description.

I have revisited your code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'paradigm_custom_category_display', 4 );
function paradigm_custom_category_display() {
    global $product;

    ob_start(); // start buffering outputted content

    if ( ! empty($product->get_short_description()) ) {
        ?>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title pp-shortdescription">
            <?php // Restricting allowed html tags (no links)
            $args = array( 'br' => [], 'p' => [], 'em' => [], 'strong' => [], 'span' => [], 'div' => [] );
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', wp_kses( $product->get_short_description(), $args ) ) ?>
        </h2>   
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="pp-block">
    <?php
    if( $author_name = get_field('author_name') ) { ?>
        <div class="pp-author"><span><?php _e('Author:'); ?> </span><?php echo $author_name; ?></div><?php   
    }
    if( $pages = get_field('pages') ) { ?>
        <div class="pp-pages"><span><?php _e('Pages:'); ?> </span><?php echo $pages; ?></div><?php   
    }   
    if( $size = get_field('size') ) { ?>
        <div class="pp-size"><span><?php _e('Size:'); ?> </span><?php echo $size; ?></div><?php   
    }   
    if( $isbn = get_field('isbn') ) {
        ?>
        <div class="pp-isbn"><span><?php _e('ISBN:'); ?> </span><?php echo $isbn; ?></div><?php   
    }   
    if( $binding = get_field('binding') ) { ?>
        <div class="pp-binding"><span><?php _e('Binding:'); ?> </span><?php echo $binding; ?></div><?php   
    }
    ?></div><?php
    
    echo ob_get_clean(); // Output the buffered content
}
```

It should work.